# ASP.NET MVC - Server software requirements?

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, iis

I've just today learned of asp.net mvc, and I'm wondering what is needed from the server-side to host this.

I suppose IIS 6 (and newer) and the .NET 3.5, is there anything else you need?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/576792/asp-mvc-server-requirements-is-server-2008-very-desirable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nope, thats it ;-) I would stick to IIS7 if at all possible though

Answer (score 4):

From MSDN: [How to: Deploy an ASP.NET MVC Application](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd410407.aspx)

Basically you need:

- .NET 3.5
- System.Web.Mvc (the ASP.NET MVC assembly)
- System.Web.Routing (a .NET Framework assembly that is required by ASP.NET MVC)
- System.Web.Abstractions (a .NET Framework assembly that is required by ASP.NET MVC)

**Routing and Abstractions** dlls are only needed if you don't have SP1.

As long as your IIS Server is serving .NET 3.5 SP1 projects fine, you shouldn't have to do anything special for MVC because it is essentially just a library.

Also, if you

Answer (score 2):

.NET 3.5 + IIS 5.1 or greater.

Answer (score 1):

IIS 5.1 is fine also.

No other needs.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your hosting environment you may find that MVC is not already installed on the server, fortunately the framework is [bin-deployable](http://haacked.com/archive/2008/11/03/bin-deploy-aspnetmvc.aspx).

Simply placing System.Web.Mvc.dll, System.Web.Routing.dll, and System.Web.Abstractions.dll in your application's bin directory should solve most deployment issues.