# ASP MVC 4 and IIS

Tags: iis, asp.net-mvc-4, windows-server-2003

I'm developping an `ASP MVC 4` application and I'm asking for `Hardware configuration` and `Windows compatibility`.

Is it possible to run this Application on `Windows 2003`? Which IIS is required?

Comment: Please show research effort. Have you tried [searching the web](http://haacked.com/archive/2008/11/26/asp.net-mvc-on-iis-6-walkthrough.aspx)? Also, duplicate of [ASP.NET MVC - Server software requirements?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2372701/asp-net-mvc-server-software-requirements).

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can run it on Windows 2003 Server. Windows 2003 Server comes with IIS 6. Here's post that shows how to configure ASP.NET MVC4 on it
http://haacked.com/archive/2008/11/26/asp.net-mvc-on-iis-6-walkthrough.aspx

Make sure you that under `Application Configuration`, you **uncheck** `Verify that file exists`.