# Getting 404 When Requesting MVC Page within Classic ASP Application

Tags: asp.net-mvc, iis-6

Current Application Server Configuration:

1. IIS 6.0
2. Windows 2003 Server Standard Edition SP2
3. .NET Framework 3.5 SP1

Current Application Architecture

1. Classic ASP 3.0, referenced within HTML Frames
2. A few ASP.NET Web Forms
3. System.Web.Mvc.dll copied to Web Application bin folder

To test the feasibility of gradually incorporating ASP.NET MVC into our existing architecture, I published an MVC application to the aforementioned classic ASP application folder.  I put in a hyperlink to the MVC page from one of the standard .html pages and I get a 404 response, telling me the requested page does not exist. I am using the same relative link that is being used on my local machine, which works fine.

Any pointers would be much appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answered [here ASP.NET MVC on IIS6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34194/asp-net-mvc-on-iis6)