# Application error with file not find?

Tags: asp.net, global-asax

I took over a asp.net project from my co-worker. When I start running the project, Application_Error() in Global.asax.cs throws an error saying file does not exist. Someone recommended using HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.ToString() to get the file path of the missing file. It returned favicon.ico. I am not sure what this means and how do I fix it?

Comment: See this similar question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1840939/asp-net-mvc-httpexception-strange-file-not-found

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It means that you are missing favicon.ico file at the required path.
In error thrown , it will show you a full path.
Please check whether you have that file in specified location.If it exists then check its properties whether it is hidden or read only.The problem must be with your missing file only.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Internet Explorer (maybe other browser) always do request on favicon.ico. If this file is found, it will be displayed as the icon of the tab or window.

You may create a favicon and put it at the root of your site.

Or maybe just do nothing with 404 error on Application_Error.

See favicon on [wikipedia](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Favicon)