# How to deployed Mvc Application on shared-hosting Server?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-2, shared-hosting

I My Web site on a HELM Control Panel. I developed my web site on MVC.But My Hosting Provider having a Following components installed on That Hosting Account framework 3.5 and IIS6. But I am Unable to Run My site it display me Page not found error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem will be that you're running under IIS6 and if its on shared hosting you're unlikely to have sufficient control to make MVC run without "cheating" a bit.

Under IIS6 requests are only routed to the ASP.NET handlers (I don't promise to get the terminology right) if they have the right extension (.aspx, .asmx, .ashx, etc) with a nice MVC URL there's no extension at all so it doesn't get see by ASP.NET and hence the request won't hit the routing within your MVC app and so you get page not found.

Under IIS7 everything (ish) goes through the ASP.NET handler and so it just works.

So a couple of links to help, here's a stackoverflow question:
[ASP.NET MVC on IIS6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34194/asp-net-mvc-on-iis6)

and here's Phil Haack on the subject:
http://haacked.com/archive/2008/11/26/asp.net-mvc-on-iis-6-walkthrough.aspx

Hope this helps.
http://haacked.com/archive/2008/11/26/asp.net-mvc-on-iis-6-walkthrough.aspx

Comment: +1 Note that on IIS7 the host provider must run the web site in an application pool set to "Integrated" mode for ASP.NET MVC to work.