# mvc 3 401.2 error with integrated security IIS(6)

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, integrated-security

We seem to be having an access problem with our MVC 3 application being hosted  IIS (6) with anonymous access disabled and integrated Windows authentication enabled.
When I navigate to the root (http://devserver/) the application works fine. If I try to navigate to a sub page (http://devserver/wtf) or click a link to a sub page I get prompted for a logon. when I enter my credentials 3 times then returns a 401.2 error.   The application is set up to redirect to the logon screen in the event that the user is not Authenticated.  This code is in the OnActionExecuting of a base controller that all controllers derive from. This method does not get hit when navigating to a sub page. Any Idea why this could be happening?

Thinks i have tried:
http://support.microsoft.com/kb/871179
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34194/asp-net-mvc-on-iis6

and just about every security setting in IIS.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out.  In the View controller base we evaluated the security, however most of our controllers have an Authorization attribute that is executed before the OnActionExecuting of the controllers. The User had not been evaluated yet so it through a 401.2 exception.